# C++ Proposal Function Returning A Type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14, constexpr

Since there are tons of proposals I would like to ask if such thing exists in C++ or if there is any proposal for doing something like this.

Idea:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr typename evalToType(int x, int y) {
    if(x > y)
        return T;
    else
        return int;
}

template <typename T, int x, int y>
evalToType<T>(x, y) SomeFunction() {
    return 0;
}
```

The motivation for this is trivial and simple which is basically that templates can be very complex and it's getting very unreadable so why not expressing the template SFINAE stuff into a constexpr which basically returns a type rather than a value.

Comment: If there _is_ a proposal like this I hope it's rejected.

Comment: @Captain Obvlious May I ask why this is a bad Idea ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's already possible, but with different syntax. It therefore provides no real benefit to introduce yet another syntax.

```
template <typename T, int x, int y>
using some_name = std::conditional_t< (x>y), T, int >;

template <typename T, int x, int y>
some_name<T, x, y> SomeFunction() {
    return 0;
}
```

as you can see the language is already quite expressive.

Comment: Oh, I also just realized that this is truly a not so good idea simply because a complex calculation could be expressed in a constexpr function. My bad :).

Answer (score 0):

Some boilerplate:

```
template<class T> struct tag{using type=T;};
template<class Tag> using type_t=typename Tag::type;

template<int x> using int_t = std::integral_constant<int, x>;
template<int x> constexpr int_t<x> int_v = {};
```

Code that returns a tagged type, based on the type of the arguments, in the form of a function (C++14):

```
template<class T, int x, int y>
constexpr auto evalToType( int_t<x>, int_t<y> )
{
   return std::conditional_t< (x>y), tag<T>, tag<int> >{};
}

template<class T, int x, int y>
type_t<decltype(evalToType(int_v<x>, int_v<y>))>
SomeFunction() {
  return 0;
}
```

you can replace `type_t<decltype()>` with:

```
#define TYPE_T(...) type_t<decltype(__VA_ARGS__)>
```

if you want.

```
template<class T, int x, int y>
TYPE_T(evalToType(int_v<x>, int_v<y>))
SomeFunction() {
  return 0;
}
```

which is sort of fun.